# Modify a Uniform circular motion experiment to lessen uncertainty

Tags: orbital-motion, error-analysis

My experiment will be the same as this one performed here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EB4poDIsY30

Independant variable: radius

Dependant variable: time

How can I make this experiment have less uncertaity?